# RecycerView won't display loaded items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

This is my first Android project. I am working on an app for tracking courses in a degree program (this is the project for a course I'm taking). I have set a RecyclerView inside a fragment. At one point the loaded items were not displayed anymore. It was working previously. I only made some changes to other parts of the app, but none to this part. I see no reason for these items to not be showing. I feel like the problem started after I clicked "Install" on an emulator update, which Android Studio suggested. I suspect the update is causing the issue, but I don't know for certain.

The code snippet below is from my fragment. I have downloaded the SQLite database and confirmed that the `course.getTermId()` matches `selectectTerm.getTermId()` for 4 items. When I open the fragment, I see a toast message that says "4 Courses loaded", so I know the issue is not with my logic here. I have tried inserting both `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` and `recyclerView.invalidate();` on the blank line right before the toast, but the items still do not show up. I have checked my layout to ensure the RecyclerView is properly sized and anchored. There's clearly something I am missing, but I am simply not seeing it. I have also confirmed that my `CourseFlatAdapter` does not have any logic errors. No exceptions are printed in Logcat. Does anyone see anything I need to do to fix this?

```java
RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerCourses);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

CourseFlatAdapter adapter = new CourseFlatAdapter();
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

courseViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CourseViewModel.class);
courseViewModel.getAllCourses().observe(this, new Observer<List<Course>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<Course> courses) {
        ArrayList<Course> filteredCourseList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Course course : courses){
            if(course.getTermId() == selectectTerm.getTermId()){
                filteredCourseList.add(course);
            }
        }
        adapter.setCourses(filteredCourseList);

        Toast.makeText(ViewTermFragment.this.getContext(), filteredCourseList.size() + " Courses loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Pass the empty filtered list to course adapter at time of initialisation and then update the same list in viewmodel observer and then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. One of the changes I had made was to put the fragment container in a `ScrollView` so the whole thing would be scrollable when there is a large amount of information. The `RecyclerView` was anchored to the bottom of the fragment and had the height set to `MatchParent` while the fragment's height was set to `WrapContent` so the `RecyclerView` ended having it's height calculated as 0 regardless of how many items it was displaying.

I changed the `RecyclerView`'s height to `WrapContent` and removed the bottom anchor. It now works as expected. Thank you to everyone who may have spent time on this.